# Strange behavior OFFSET ... ROWS FETCH NEXT ... ROWS ONLY after ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I see very strange behavior of construction like

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY ... OFFSET ... ROWS FETCH NEXT ... ROWS ONLY
```

I made simple example to display it (SQL Server version: 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) ):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp( c1 int NOT NULL, c2 varchar(MAX) NULL) 
INSERT INTO #temp (c1,c2) VALUES (1,'test1')
INSERT INTO #temp (c1,c2) VALUES (2,NULL)
INSERT INTO #temp (c1,c2) VALUES (3,'test3')
INSERT INTO #temp (c1,c2) VALUES (4,NULL)
INSERT INTO #temp (c1,c2) VALUES (5,NULL)
```

First query:

```
select * from #temp 
ORDER BY c2 DESC
```

Result is ok:

```
3   test3
1   test1
2   NULL
4   NULL
5   NULL
```

Second query:

```
select * from #temp 
ORDER BY c2 DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Result has another sorting:

```
3   test3
1   test1
4   NULL
```

And last query:

```
select * from #temp 
ORDER BY c2 DESC
OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Result is very strange and invalid in my opinion (I need get two records that not contains in previous result, but instead I get record with id=4 second time):

```
4   NULL
2   NULL
```

Can anyone explain why SQL server works so strange?

Comment: There's nothing weird or funky going on here - since all your rows with c1 = 2, 4, 5 all have `NULL` as their `c2` value, and you're sorting *only* by `c2`, there's no guarantee as to *which* of the rows with c2 = `NULL` will come first. If you need more control, you need to use `ORDER BY C2 DESC, c1` or something like that - an ordering that will **clearly define** how the rows are sorted - even if all of them have `c2 = NULL` values....

Answer (score 1):

Use unique key column with this type of case:

```
select * from #temp 
ORDER BY c2, c1 DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Never faced ordering problem.